# Нумерация с единицы

Tags: jquery

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать нумерацию не с 0 а с 1?

```
function updateTableNumeration() {
    $('.table tbody tr').each(function(i) {
          $(this).find('td:first').text(i+".");
    });
}    


$.ajax({
    success: function (res) {
        updateTableNumeration();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(this).find('td:first').text((i + 1) + ".");
```

---

> как сделать инверт нумерации

```
function updateTableNumeration() {
  var count = $('.table tbody tr').length;
  $('.table tbody tr').each(function(i) {
    $(this).find('td:first').text((count - i) + ".");
  });
}
```

Comment: Да отлично, а можно чтоб последня цифра была вверху?

Comment: @Never3D Конечно, можно. "Вверху" чего?

Comment: td:first это первый элемент, а как выбрать последний элемент таблицы?

Comment: @Never3D Не понял, как связаны между собой эти вопросы. Последняя ячейка таблицы: `$(".table td:last")`

Comment: Вообщем как сделать инверт нумерации?)

Comment: спасибо большое вам

Comment: @Never3D Лучшая благодарность - исправить "еденицу" на "единицу" в заголовке вопроса ).

Comment: ))) спешил когда вопрос задавал, исправил)